# Python matplotlib manipulating to use it in the plot title

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

assume I've the following variable

```
roundi = theta_result_lasso.round(2)
[ 0.   -2.36]
```

where theta_result_lasso.round are just two values.

The line for my plot title is

```
ax.set_title(r'Globales Minimum $\hat \beta$ = {}'.format(roundi), fontsize=20)
```

producing this:

[image]

is there a way to replace the "." after the zero by a "," and descreasing the disance between the two values as it should look like a "vector" ?

It should look like this:

```
[0, -2.36]
```

If you Need further informations, I'll provide an example

Comment: what is `type(roundi)`?

Comment: class 'numpy.ndarray'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array consist of two variables every time, the easiest would be to format your string something like the following

```
roundi = [0.0,-2.36]
titlestring = 'Globales Minimum $\hat \beta$ = [{:0.0f}, {:0.2f}]'.format(roundi[0],roundi[1])
```

The values in `roundi` are accessed and formatted individually here.
This will result in the following formatting

```
'Globales Minimum $\\hat \x08eta$ = [0, -2.36]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ax.set_title(r'Globales Minimum $\hat \beta$ = {}'.format(str(roundi) ), 
fontsize=20)
```

Comment: This would result in `[ 0,   -2,36]` (two commas)